# Stack elements above each other inside a container

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have multiple elements inside a list. I want to stack all of them above each other. Using `position: absolute` on them archieved this result however I cant seem to figure out on how to keep them inside their grid space (I am using the [Materialize grid system](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)). I tried adding a wrapper with `position: relative` but I could not get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/b6naew9h/12/

How can I stack all list elements and still respect the grid?

Comment: did the list stack list be in same line with circle.or the circle should be in new line centered?both stacked ul and circle centered?

Comment: The circle should not stack and get pushed down by the list.

Comment: Yes, I used Taruckus answer and added a padding to the `row` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a containing element of the li's to position:relative, like the responsive item (or another element inside it), then the li's to position:absolute.

```
.rel {position:relative;} // this could be on .col or a new element inside it
li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nft3mvj6/